# How to solve this Treeset program?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

This is a java question. I just want to ask why is 9 added to the original list `ts` also?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      TreeSet<Integer> ts=new TreeSet<Integer>();
      ts.add(1);
      ts.add(8);
      ts.add(6);
      ts.add(4);
      SortedSet<Integer> ss = ts.subSet(2, 10);
      ss.add(9);
      System.out.println(ts);
      System.out.println(ss);
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: [subset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean)) returns a *view* of the original.

Answer (score 2):

As Alowaniak stated in the comments, `subset` returns only a view of the original set, so changes are reflected to both sets. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean)) says:

> The returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa.

You could, for example, create a new set based on the subset:

```
Set<Integer> ss = new TreeSet<Integer>(ts.subSet(2, 10));
```

to prevent this behavior.